# why do some android events stop propagation and other don't need to?

Tags: java, android, listener

why do some event listeners return boolean and some don't?

what is the meaning of `stopping propagation`?

for instance:

`public void onClick(View v)`

`public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)`

Comment: This is pretty interesting question. It's quite surprised for me, that there is still no any valuable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html
They have a note which says:

> Note: Android will call event handlers first and then the appropriate
>   default handlers from the class definition second. As such, returning
>   true from these event listeners will stop the propagation of the event
>   to other event listeners and will also block the callback to the
>   default event handler in the View. So be certain that you want to
>   terminate the event when you return true.

What I understand about 'stopping propagation' is this: say you have a `TextView` nested deep in other `ViewGroup` like `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout`, a click on the text view is automatically a click on the `ViewGroup`. This click is then 'propagated' down till it reaches the target text view. My understanding is based on this:

> Remember that hardware key events are always delivered to the View
>   currently in focus. They are dispatched starting from the top of the
>   View hierarchy, and then down, until they reach the appropriate
>   destination. If your View (or a child of your View) currently has
>   focus, then you can see the event travel through the
>   dispatchKeyEvent() method. As an alternative to capturing key events
>   through your View, you can also receive all of the events inside your
>   Activity with onKeyDown() and onKeyUp().

Comment: but then why `public void onClick(View v)` doesn't return boolean value?

Comment: why do some event listeners return boolean and some don't?

Comment: Recommended read: http://balpha.de/2013/07/android-development-what-i-wish-i-had-known-earlier/, specifically "Propagation of events" section.